# How to fail silently and catch exceptions in React Native?

Tags: react-native

When my App is in production, I would like to avoid the red error screen if anything bad happens.

How can I make it so that instead of throwing an exception and showing the error screen, the app simply restarts and goes back to the home page?

Answer (score 1):

While Richard Kho's answer might help out on known issues, it won't provide "silent failure".

There are a few tools out there that will help you catch all errors, such as [react-native-report-error](https://github.com/VansonLeung/react-native-error-reporter). However, it won't fail silently, either.

In the mean time, a few steps will help you achieve this:

1. Always initialize props/state with default values;
2. Wrap function in Promises or try/catch blocks;

It's not magic, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have listeners for specific events and fire a callback in the event that any of those listeners fire.

For example, I have a listener for a lack in internet connection using `NetInfo`, as well as the app being opened/closed using `AppStateIOS`. My `getInitialState` function sets two properties:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      currentState: AppStateIOS.currentState,
      isConnected: null
    }
  },
```

Then I have some listeners and handlers:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
      (isConnected) => { this.setState({isConnected}); }
    );
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectivityChange);

  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    AppStateIOS.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  },

  handleAppStateChange: function(state) {
    this.setState({
      currentState: state
    });
  },

  handleConnectivityChange: function(connection) {
    this.setState({
      isConnected: connection
    })
  },
```

My `render` method is dependent on my state:

```
  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.isConnected) {
      return (
        this.renderLoading()
          )
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView url={this.props.url} />
      </View>
      )
  },
```

Comment: I've noticed that `NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done()` always returns true even when I disable wifi and enable airplane mode. Any ideas?